# Is it possible to share the application data on google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

There's a nice feature on google drive that allows an application to store data not visible for users.

https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata

Is it possible to share this application data between users, just like other google drive files?

Larsi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't share appdata files within the Drive's existing permissions model. Appdata content is supposed to be exclusive to the application. If you try to change permissions for an appdata file, you'll receive a `403` with the following error message:

```
Method not supported for appdata contents
```

Comment: Is this still the case in drive api v3?

Comment: Yeah, still the case in Drive API v3