# Sharing of data on Google servers maintaining Access Control List

Tags: google-drive-api, access-control, google-drive-android-api

Can i share the files which are uploaded in the Application Folder with other Google account users ?

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder

I want the user uploading the file to maintain an Access Control List.
If Appdata does not support it, is there any other alternative provided by google for it?

Comment: This question is the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017153/is-it-possible-to-share-the-application-data-on-google-drive) old question.

Comment: hi Luis, went through that also. That is why i asked for any alternative solution.